# Looking for python video editing/processing capabilities that will work with Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, video, video-processing, editing

Does know any python video editing/processing libraries or frameworks that work with Google App Engine? I need to pro grammatically edit video files (adding a soundtrack, layering video clips on top etc.) on my App Engine site.

Comment: any update on this? did you end of using GAE or have success with AWS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With most video/audio codecs written in C for maximum portability, and any muxing libraries being written in C for speed working with large byte streams, finding these features in pure python libraries is going to be difficult.

If you could tie yourself down to just a single codec/container format you could probably port something to pure python but you're in for a long slog if you want to build something as diverse as ffmpeg in pure python.

I would not recommend this sort of task for AppEngine, even with backends, I think you would be severally limiting yourself by forcing this on AppEninge as well as making your task much harder than it would be if you looked at alternative solutions.

I would get myself a VPS or EC2 instance, build a little webservice around [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) and send tasks to it from my main AppEngine application.

Comment: How difficult will it be to build a webservice like that with EC2? Because I think that's definitely something I'm going to need help with.

Comment: @yourfriendzak If you run into problems, you can post specific questions here on SO, and we the community will lend you a hand!