# Extract chunks from video file

Tags: python, video, extract

Is it possible to write Python code that gets a video file (mpg, avi, wmv, mov, etc) and a time interval (e.g. from 5_min-10_secs-11_ms to 10-min_15-secs-40_ms) and create a small video from this interval?

I know this is possible with ffmpeg, mencoder and other programs, but I'd like to do this in Python code.

Comment: I'd say the path least annoying will be to just shell out to `ffmpeg`; the CLI seems to be the only interface to the ffmpeg libraries that's guaranteed to both remain up-to-date, and expose all the high-level functionality. You could also try using the Python bindings for [GStreamer](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/) which also seems to work at this high a level, but it looks like a pretty complex library.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "do this in python code". Do you mean: a) pure python, b) python bindings to an external library, or c) a system call to e.g. ffmpeg.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra I mean to create output from inputs defined in the question.

Comment: I understand that, I asked more specifically what you meant by "do this in python code".

Comment: I've asked this myself a few times. There is still no python native way to do it - mencoder or ffmpeg from the command line is the best approach.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra If you know more possibilities to achieve the goal it's even better and we can compare the solutions.

Comment: @bjorn I think one of the reasons why there is no python native solution is because using a system call works so well. In additionc I can imagine that a pure python implementation would be quite slow...

Comment: @xralf, do you like any of the answers? It seems you have not upvoted any answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Googling for "python library to edit video file" lead me right back to SO:

- [Best video manipulation library for Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220866/best-video-manipulation-library-for-python)
- [Looking for python video editing/processing capabilities that will work with Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6872388/looking-for-python-video-editing-processing-capabilities-that-will-work-with-goo)

In addition to getting this kind of functionality from a library, I often use a system call (os.system or subprocess) to call mencoder or ffmpeg. You could write a function to do this, in pythonesque pseudo code:

```
def getVideoChunk(filepath, timerange, outputfile):
    retcode = systemcall("ffmpeg %s %s", filepath, timerange, outputfile)
    return retcode
```

Ofcourse you need to choose a way of running tge systemcall and you need to learn some ffmpeg syntax.

EDIT (based on comments) Assuming the syntax of mmpeg is like:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mpg -sameq -ss 00:02:00 -t 00:02:00 output.mpg
```

The call would look like:

```
getVideoChunk("input.mpg", "00:02:00", "output.mpg")
```

and the system call bit would look like (note I use os.system):

```
os.system("ffmpeg -i %s -sameq -ss %s -t %s %s" % (filepath, timerange, timerange, outputfile))
```

note that this code is also pseuodo python code and I have not tested it...the code is purely instructional.

Comment: Thanks, could you please show the call of getVideoChunk() how does timerange look like?

Comment: You could make it a string with the correct ffmpg syntax. Take a look qt ffmpeg.

Comment: Let's say the command would be as follows `ffmpeg -i input.mpg -sameq -ss 00:02:00 -t 00:02:00 output.mpg` in command line. I'm not sure how would your function definition and call look like?

Comment: I edited my answer to include this.